# Inject dependencies into ES2015 module

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

Is it possible to inject dependencies into ES2015 modules like in other programming languages like C# or Java? If I import a module I create a hard dependency to it and can not change it later at runtime. For example I have following JavaScript code:

```
import Animal from './dog';

class Person {
  feedAnimal() {
    new Animal().feed();
  }
}
```

I am importing the dog module. But what if I want to change it to a cat? At the moment I have to modify line 1 by hand but in some situations I want it configurable from the outside so that under some conditions there should be a cat and under some other conditions it should be a cat. All that things that can be done with classical dependency injection.

I know there are some DI frameworks out there like [Scatter](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/scatter), [Electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte), [Wire](https://github.com/cujojs/wire) and so on but unfortunately most of them require some special syntax and are **not** made for [ES2015 modules](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/).

Comment: How would you want dependency injection to work? You could do `class Person { constructor(Animal) { this.Animal = Animal; } feedAnimal() { new this.Animal().feed() } }`, but it sounds like you expect something more advanced.

Comment: I am not sure if [`require-inject`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-inject) supports that, but you might want to take a look.

Comment: @lyschoening thank you but I want to change internal module dependencies like I would write an unit test.

Comment: @thefourtheye thank you but the thing is that I do *not* require anything. Requiering is a CommonJS related thing. I use the shiny new ES2015 import feature.

Comment: You could probably hijack the module loader one way or the other. Not that I recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved over to [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). With SystemJS you can make dynamic imports like `System.import('foo').then(() => console.log('Loaded));`

Another advantage is that System will be the new ECMAScript standard module loader system.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically define dependencies. [See this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js):

> **Question:** ES6 variable import name in node.js?
>
> **Answer:** Not with the import statement. import and export are defined in such a way that they are statically analyzable, so they cannot depend on runtime information.

Comment: Hmm ok. Too bad. Do you know any workaround or something like that for this?

Comment: A module loader like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/README.md) would allow what you want.

Comment: I ask myself how do the all write unit tests if I can't mock any dependencies in my module to test?

Comment: Mocking a dependency means replacing or altering the actual dependency without affecting the code that uses it, not altering the code that uses a dependency to use a different dependency. I hope that makes sense, please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: I know that. Because of this I created the question above ;-)

Comment: @sdgluck: I think OP is asking exactly for this kind of dependency-*injection*, from the outside, which does not need dynamic/variable import names. It just needs a mocking module name *resolver*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader) to achieve this if you are bundling with Webpack.

Hopefully this helps someone who stumbles upon this old post.