# Can I use a function to load a module in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-router, es6-module-loader

When using ES6 module loading syntax, like so...

```
import LoginPage from '../../pages/login';
```

... is it possible to use a function to replace `../../pages` with a function so that I could have something like this...

```
import LoginPage from page_path('login');
```

This line is repeated for all pages I am importing, so if it is in a function I can update all paths quickly if my file structure were to change.

Trying it out, it would seem it doesn't work. Is there a smarter way to do this in ES6?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29168433/218196 .

Comment: _"Is there a smarter way to do this in ES6_" This **is** the smart way because a good IDE can update the paths automatically.