# How do I use a template literal in an import statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When this line is executed:

```
import stats from `./${process.env.STATS}`
```

the error below is reported:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token `

The module can be loaded successfully with the expression:

```
const stats = require(`./${process.env.STATS}`);
```

The `import` statement seems to require a regular string as it works with the statement:

```
import stats from './statsdir'
```

where `'./statsdir'` is the value of `process.env.STATS`.

**Why does the error occur?**

Comment: what node version are you using?

Comment: I am using version `6.0`. I'm also using `babel-cli` to compile the source files.

Comment: if you are using babel, are you loading the correct presets in your .babelrc?

Comment: I'm currently using the `es2015` preset.

Comment: can you show us your .babelrc and the way you are executing your app? It seems like it's not loading your presets

Comment: Not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js

Comment: The error occurs because import only takes a string.

Comment: @qop this has nothing to do with Babel or presets. It's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 18):

> Why does the error occur?

It seems you found the answer yourself:

> The `import` statement seems to require a regular string

Exactly. `import` needs a string *literal*. It import location cannot be dynamic.

Related: [ES6 variable import name in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js)

Comment: Well this is a bummer if one needs to prepend "./" if one is in a browser as a template literal would shorter the code substantially.