# String literal expected. when importing in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
import * as app from `${process.cwd()}/server`
```

It give me the error:

```
[ts] String literal expected.
```

Can I not interpolate strings when importing?

Comment: No; TypeScript needs to be able to resolve the import at compile time.

Comment: you can use `require` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36955213/11603006

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not legal syntax in ES6 modules or in TypeScript. Part of the ES6 module spec is that dependencies are always statically resolvable.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to **Dynamically import** a module. Unfortunately, this is impossible using the ES6 import/export mechanism which is not analyzed in runtime (nothing to do with TypeScript so far).

In order import your module dynamically and avoid the tsc error I'd suggest using the common.js **require** mechanism (which does allow dynamic import):

```
const your_module = require(`${process.cwd()}/server`);
```

Note that whenever your variable is not certained to be a string (unlike your template string example) I'd reccommend using the mentioned solution alongside Typescript type assertion. this should look like this:

```
const your_module = require(<string>process.env.myNodeModulePackageName);
```

Edit:

In ES2020 the import statement evolved to return a promise, supporting dynamic imports. So if you are willing to use the native import mechanism (rather then common.js) you should do as follows:

```
const your_module = await import (`${process.cwd()}/server`)
```

(note that your `tsconfig.json` file should be configured to:

`"target": "es2017"`
`"module": "esnext"`

(will allow you to use `top level await` as well)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did this which is illegal apparently:

```js
import { two }, one from "./file";
```

While it should be this:

```js
import one, { two } from "./file";
```