# How to fetch a native ES6 module using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using the FF Dev build that supports ES6 modules. When I use

```
<script type="module" src="./script.js">
```

script.js triggers the download of other scripts in its import section at the start of the file, but that does not happen when I use:

```
fetch("./script.js")
```

I did not find how to specify the script type in the Fetch API.

Comment: sry, meant script element

Comment: `fetch` just grabs the *text* of the resource, it doesn't interpret it (well, XML gets parsed). Why would you use `fetch` instead of a `script` element?

Comment: What do you need this for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What do you mean by "XML gets parsed"?

Comment: @guest: My bad, I was thinking of XMLHttpRequest. `fetch` has a method for doing read-to-completion and parsing JSON, and similarly form data, but not XML as far as I see on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something with the script after you fetch it? Since fetch returns a promise, as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), you have to do something with the resource after you get it. Fetch won't execute the code in that file, it just retrieves it.