# Variables in import statement

Tags: javascript, import, vuejs2

Is it possible to do something like

```
import Vue from '../vendor/vue';
    import slides from '../data/'+$root.name'+.json'; 

    Vue.component('mycomponent', {
```

Comment: No...for the second import. Because you can't export anything from a `.json` file.

Comment: Just copy pasting your question gave me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately import statements must use static names.

There is a proposal to add a dynamic `module()` function that will load on the fly: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

The proposed syntax is:

```
import('./' + dynamicFileName + '.js')
.then(module => {
    // use module
})
.catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
```

It looks to be currently active: https://github.com/tc39/proposals

It looks like there is a polyfill here: https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader

Another issue is that you can't directly import json into JavaScript. The below approach might be what you're after:

Slides file:

```
export const slides = [
    { ... }
];
```

Then import the file with either a static module path or with the dynamic import polyfill.