# VueJS: importing a (sass) file dynamically (from a variable, possibly process.env)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import

how can I import a dynamically file from environment variables?

My scope is to include a general theme scss for a specific client, to my app.vue (or main.ts)

I would like to do something like this:

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import"./themes/" + process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT + "/assets/scss/theme.scss";
</style>
```

or

```
import "./themes/" + process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT + "/assets/scss/theme.scss";
```

How can I accomplish this?

if I do it via *`import`* (on top of main.ts) it says

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

if I do it via *`<style>`* and *`@import`* (inside my app.vue)

> undefined
>                      ^
>         Media query expression must begin with '('

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after checking the net for dynamically importing modules in ES6 I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js) which suggests just using import() like a function, and it works fine:

```
import("./themes/" + process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT + "/assets/scss/theme.scss");
```