# Vue dynamic component template not working for promise

Tags: vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

```
<template>
  <component :is="myComponent" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    component: String,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      myComponent: '',
    };
  },

  computed: {
    loader() {
      return () => import(`../components/${this.component}`);
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.loader().then(res => {
      // components can be defined as a function that returns a promise;
      this.myComponent = () => this.loader();
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Reference:

https://medium.com/scrumpy/dynamic-component-templates-with-vue-js-d9236ab183bb

[Vue js import components dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080549/vue-js-import-components-dynamically)

Console throw error "this.loader() is not a function" or "this.loader().then" is not a function.

Comment: Try changing ```loader()``` from a computed property to a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're seeing that error, as `loader` is clearly defined as a computed prop that returns a function.

However, the `created` hook seems to call `loader()` twice (the second call is unnecessary). That could be simplified:

```js
export default {
  created() {
    // Option 1
    this.loader().then(res => this.myComponent = res)

    // Option 2
    this.myComponent = () => this.loader()
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-dynamic-component-in-vue-fcnrr?file=/src/components/DynamicComponent.vue)

Even simpler would be to rename `loader` with `myComponent`, getting rid of the `myComponent` data property:

```js
export default {
  //data() {
  //  return {
  //    myComponent: '',
  //  };
  //},

  computed: {
    //loader() {
    myComponent() {
      return () => import(`../components/${this.component}`);
    },
  },
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-dynamic-component-in-vue-forked-df831?file=/src/components/DynamicComponent.vue)

Comment: Thank you! This is 2.0 demo. I found we need add one more thing in 3.0.


this.myComponent = shallowRef(defineAsyncComponent(() => this.loader()));