# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when import in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some code for my discord js bot.
That code should get all commands in commands dir.
When `import command from commandsDir + files[i];` was `let command = require(commandsDir + files[i])` everything was fine but:

```
getCommands = function () {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(commandsDir).filter(file => (
    !fs.statSync(commandsDir + file).isDirectory() &&
    !file.startsWith("!") &&
    file.endsWith(".js")));
  let commands = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    try {
      import command from commandsDir + files[i];
      commands[command.name] = command;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  return commands;
}
getCommand = function (commandName) {
  if (commands[commandName]) return commands[commandName];

  for (let i in commands)
    if (commands[i].aliases.includes(commandName)) return commands[i];
}
```

When i run that code i get an `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error in `import command from commandsDir + files[i];`:
idk why but please help me fix this error (if possible) without any other things.
UPD: Here example of my command.js file

```
module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    aliases: [],
    description: "test i guess",
    usage: "",
    run(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`hello`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find more informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js). But in short you probably need dynamic imports. (call `import(commandsDir + files[i])`) according to Nicolai Schmid answer.