# Webpack raw-loader not working after Angular update

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-localize

I have recently updated my Angular application to V12. I am using Angular's own Internationalization library `@angular/localize`. I am using webpack's `raw-loader` to load the xlf translation files as a string in my **main.ts** using the following code

```
const locale = document['locale'] as string;
const translations =   require(`raw-loader!./assets/locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`).default;

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
providers: [
{ provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale },
{ provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }
 ]
});
```

After the update I get the following error
**Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader'**

What could be the reason for this? Is there any way other than raw-loader?

Comment: I am sort of facing the same issue. Any luck on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. i had to redo everything using the angular way. Previously I was using raw-loader to load the selected locale file, now I use ng build --localize to build all locales and based on the locale selected I append in the url e.g localhost:200/en or localhost:4200/de etc

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue migrating the angular version ,and i've solved it installing it with `npm install raw-loader --save-dev` . It is because angular 12 now uses webpack5. If you don't solve the problem try to change const translations =   require(`raw-loader!./assets/locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`).default; to an ES import dynamic declaration like  in your case that you use a variable ${locale} inside it, maybe you can take a look at this post [ES6 variable import name in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js) . and use !!raw-loader... instead of raw-loader

Answer (score 0):

**Since webpack version 5 the use of loaders like the [raw-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) is deprecated and replaced with a concept called [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules).**

For this to work you first need to define how assets should be loaded. This is done in the webpack's config. A replacement for the `raw-loader` is the [asset/source type](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#source-assets):

#### webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.xlf/,
       type: 'asset/source',
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

After that you can just import your asset files like any other local dependency:

#### main.ts

```js
const translations = require(`./assets/locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`).default;
```