# require a file on condition with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, require

In my next.js + express.js (custom server within next) app, there is a flow of follows:

1. user selects a parameter with  drop down menu.
2. upon her/his selection of parameter, a process is executed in the backend.
   2.1. upon the parameter, I define the a filePath, like filePath = "myPath/parameter/coords.js"
3. when the process is finished, it creates a file and writes some coordinates info.
4. when the process is finished I "require(file)" and will be showing the coordinates on my leaflet comp.

Therefore
I need something like this

```
if (processIsFinished) {
   const coords = require(filePath)
```

}

My questions are:

1. I cannot define filePath with a variable. When I say /Users/..../parameter/coords.js, it is ok, no error (if there is already a file, which refers to my question-2) but since parameter is selected by user, I want the filePath defined as a var.
   I tried:

   const coords = require(filePath)

   const coords = require(`${filePath}`)

   const coords = require(`myPath/${parameter}/coords`)

   const coords = require('' + filePath)

all did not work...
how can we define the path in require with a variable?

2. when there is no file, the "require" throws error, even if it is put in a conditional statement block (if statement).
   how can we make it work, like, if the "processIsFinished" then execute the require statement, because then there will be such a file.

Thanks...

Comment: Why not Nextjs Dynamic Imports? https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: I already used it dynamic() with my leaflet component (with no SSR option). Map is already loaded. But to be frank I was just searching this idea, like, dynamically load ANOTHER map instance when "processIsFinished"... I will try to do this, as I am also new to next. thanks.

Comment: next dynamic() import did not work when requiring "not existing file"... whatever the case require needs a file, empty or not...

Answer (score 0):

imports cannot be made with dynamic path names, this includes the require function.

but there is a workaround for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/how-to-perform-a-variable-es6-import). Results may vary as its non conformant.