# how to import custom js modules using es module imports

Tags: node.js, esmodules

When using the commonjs I used to import custom modules like this:-

```
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
```

after switching to es module type I can no longer use the __dirname without creating one manually

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

import date from __dirname + "/date.js"
```

When I use this it shows me "unexpected identifier __dirname" on the import line.

date.js is in the same level of directory as this code file is in.

How do I import custom js module using es module syntax?
Please help

Thank you

Comment: Actually, I just found it's a duplicate. Does this answer your question? [How to perform a “variable” ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/how-to-perform-a-variable-es6-import)

Comment: Just use relative paths instead of absolutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `date.js` file is in the same directory, you can use relative path:

```
import date from "./date.js"
```